# BibLaTeX prints entry that is not cited

Tags: biblatex

The following MWE ends up with three bibliography entries, although there are only two cited. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
    natbib=true,
    hyperref=true,
    bibstyle=ext-authoryear,
    giveninits=true,
    uniquename=false,
    innamebeforetitle,
    articlein=false,
    useprefix=true,
    sortlocale=de_DE_phonebook,
]{biblatex}
    \defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
    \section*{#1}%
    }
    \addbibresource{TEST-Bib-Sorting.bib}
    \defbibheading{subbibliography}[\refname]{\subsection*{#1}}

    \DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
    \AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%     Biblatex-Einstellungen                                      %%%
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{dashed=false}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addperiod\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{innametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

% this is tricky, we want to merge the round brackets around
% the "ed."/"eds." and the year
% the idea is to only open the brackets in the editor string
% and the close it in the labelyear
% since editortype might also be used for editors of @in...
% types where this can't happen, we need a test
\newtoggle{bbx@editor@sortname}
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\toggletrue{bbx@editor@sortname}%
     \usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%
  \togglefalse{bbx@editor@sortname}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx@editor@sortname}
    {\bibopenparen #1}
    {\mkbibparens{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx@editor@sortname}
    {\addcomma\space
     \iffieldnum{edition}
       {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
        \csgundef{abx@field@edition}}
       {}%
     #1\bibcloseparen}
    {\mkbibparens{%
       \iffieldnum{edition}
         {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
          \csgundef{abx@field@edition}}
         {}%
       #1}}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
%% tricky bit END

\DeclareFieldFormat{translatortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{pages}{
  \printfield{pages}%
}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addcolon}\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

%%% Titel kursiv
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,incollection]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook,incollection]{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}

\DeclareSortingNamekeyTemplate{
  \keypart{
    \namepart{prefix}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{family}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{given}
  }
  \keypart{
    \namepart{suffix}
  }
}

\renewbibmacro*{incollection:parent}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:innamebeforetitle}
    {\usebibmacro{in:editor+others}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{innametitledelim}}\newblock}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{edition}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{barevolume+volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{introcite:plain}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:articlein}{\usebibmacro{in:}}{}%
  \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}
  \usebibmacro{pages}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{issn}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{introcite:plain}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{edition}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{barevolume+volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{introcite:plain}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{crosscite}{incollection:parent}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \setunit{\adddot\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  % with default inheritance 'related' is not inherited,
  % so the test is not actually necessary
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:related} and not test {\iffieldxref{related}}}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{filecontents}{TEST-Bib-Sorting.bib}
@Incollection{Fowler:2000:First,
  author   = {Fowler, D. P.},
  year     = {2000},
  title    = {First thoughts on closure: problems and prospects},
  pages    = {239–83},
  crossref = {Fowler:2000},
}

@Incollection{Fowler:2000:Second,
  author   = {Fowler, D. P.},
  year     = {2000},
  title    = {Second thoughts on closure},
  pages    = {284–307},
  crossref = {Fowler:2000},
}

@Book{Fowler:2000,
  editor    = {Fowler, D. P.},
  year      = {2000},
  title     = {Roman constructions. Readings in postmodern Latin},
  publisher = {Oxford},
  booktitle = {Roman constructions. Readings in postmodern Latin},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

%\citet{Fowler:2000},
\citet{Fowler:2000:Second},
\citet{Fowler:2000:First}


\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you have crossref's in the bib.

Comment: Yes. I already tried the following. When deleting the crossref from entry `Fowler:2000:Second`, the result is perfectly fine, i.e. there are only two entries printed (`Fowler:2000:First` and `Fowler:2000:Second`).

Comment: That's minimal?

Comment: Check the description of crossref and the mincrossrefs option in the documentation.

Comment: The standard setting of `mincrossrefs` is `mincrossrefs=2`. That means that an entry is automatically added to the bibliography (as if it had been `\nocite`'d) if two different entries `crossref` it. `Fowler:2000` is `crossref`'d by both `Fowler:2000:First` and `Fowler:2000:Second` and so it ends up in the bibliography as if cited.

Comment: @JPi: Call it WE then. :)

Comment: @moewe: I just fixed it, thanks. What I'm curious about is that in my real files there was no `Fowler:2000` printed in the bibliography. Even though there were two entries `crossref`fing it. The (M)WE above is different. --- Anyway, it is working now fine.

Comment: The two lines `\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}` that remain in the code, but are not used, suggest you might be filtering your bibliography to make sure only actually cited entries are added to the list. Since `Fowler:2000` is not explicitly cited it would not be printed in the bibliography, but it would still be there for all other purposes (disambiguation, `extradate` letter, ...).

Comment: That's right. It was indeed nor printed among the actually `cited` entries, but neither among the `notcited` ones.
I have several entries that are actually cited. Those will be printed as _Bibliography_. Some other entries that I do not cite in my paper, but I want to be printed anyway, are listed as _Further readings_. I think this trouble is caused by using the `refsection` environment together with the `keywords` field in the `bib` file. Since `Fowler:2000` didn't have the correct keyword it was not printed where I expected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have crossref's in the bib entries.

From the documentation:

> If the number of child entries referencing a specific parent entry
>   hits a certain threshold, the parent entry is automatically added to
>   the bibliography even if it has not been cited explicitly. The
>   threshold is settable with the `mincrossrefs` package option ...